# How expensive is it to compute an image convolution

Tags: image-processing, neural-network, convolution

I was wondering how computationally expensive it is to compute an image convolution. That is, to convolve an NxN image with a 3x3 or 5x5 convolution filter? It seems like this would be a costly operation, because there is a lot of multiplication and then additions. However, I imagine that some of these operations have been optimized on GPUs and in the programming language compilers. Hence I was not sure how to gauge the costliness.

When I talk about cost, I am referring to the different dimensions of cost, such as memory allocations, and number of operations. I suppose some of this cost can be reduced using smart caching of data, though the multiplication and addition operations are not reduced that way.

Certainly a lot of neural network models rely on convolutions for images, text, time series, etc. However, I was not sure how expensive it was to compute the convolution of an image with a filter, compared to say the gradient descent step. Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: You could, of course, compute the number of operations involved in image convolution. 
But for what I think you're asking, I think the best solution is to run a few computational experiments and draw your own conclusions.

Comment: @NNN yes thanks for the response. I was thinking about this, and it is a good option. My only reservation is that a lot of these hardware and software architectures are optimized now, so if I write the code in one way I might get one set of results, but if I code things a different way, I might get different results. But I suppose this is always the way, haha. So yeah, I can write some benchmarking loops and compare the speeds of different operations, say the convolution step versus the gradient descent step. Thanks for the suggestion.